# why assignment operators return non boolean value

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I tested result this javascript expressions in chrome browser console (output result is bold):
a = false
***false***
b = false
***false***
a||b
***false***
a|=b
***0***
why in the last expression (a|=b) does not return a boolean?

UPDATE:
Can I do this?
a=!!(a|=b)

Comment: Take a look at this http://wtfjs.com/

Comment: Well the result of the expression is 0 because of weak-typing. So it returns `0`.

Comment: It doesn't return a boolean but the value of the assigned variable. a becomes boolean, b becomes boolean, a|b is an OR between booleans so it's a boolean and last one is a bitwise or (and you bit operators works with integers, not with booleans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise operators treat their operands as a set of 32 bits (zeros and ones) and return standard JavaScript numerical values.

Taken from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't return a boolean but the value of the assigned variable and the last statement changes the value of `a` from a boolean to an integer:

```
Operation      Type                        Value                   Output
               A           B           A             B       
a = false      bool        undefined   false         undefined     false1
b = false      bool        bool        false         false         false1
a || b         bool        bool        false         false         false2
a |= b         integer     bool        0             false         03
```

<sup>1</sup> The value of the last variable assigned (in this case `a` or `b` with the value `false`).

<sup>2</sup> The value of the logical operator `||` (logical OR): `false OR false === false`. Let me simplify this a little bit (too much?) but because `a` is false then you have the value of `b`. Just take a look at **§ 11.11**.

<sup>3</sup> Bitwise operator `|` (bitwise OR, see **§ 11.10**), specifications says that its operands must be evaluated to their *value* (in your case a boolean) then converted to a signed 32 bit integer, result is another signed 32 bit integer. From **§ 9.3** we know that conversion from boolean to number produces 0 for `false` and 1 for `true`, they're then converted to 32 bit signed integer according to **§ 9.5** (here you have 0 again).

**References**
[JavaScript language specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Because `|` is not a boolean, but a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) which acts on signed 32-bit-integers - numbers. And so the boolean `false` inputs are first casted to zeros before the operator is applied.

Also, the [logical OR operator `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) is not boolean as well. It just [short-circuit evaluates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to the value of the left (if truthy) or right expression, which is of boolean type in your case. If you'd used `var a=0, b=0` it would yield `0` as well.